# Show that $(a,b)$ is open in the usual topology of $\mathbb{R}$ and $[a,b)$ is not

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

I am little bit stumped by this proof.

> Show that $(a,b), a < b$ and $ a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ is open in the usual topology of $\mathbb{R}$ and $[a,b)$ is not

Recall that the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$ is

$$\tau_u = \{U \subseteq \mathbb{R} | \forall x \in U, \exists \delta > 0, \text{ s.t. }(x-\delta, x+\delta) \subseteq U\}$$

The part for $[a,b)$ is trivial, we can pick $x = a$, then the conclusion follows.

But how do I show that $\forall x \in (a,b), \exists \delta > 0$? Can someone provide a starting point or a sketch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\delta = \frac 12 \min\{ |x-a|, |x-b|\}$ would do. Note that (check!)

$$a < x-\delta <x <x+ \delta <b. $$

Of course $\delta$ depends on $x$.

Answer (score 0):

You want to find $\delta>0$ such that $x-\delta>a$ and $x+\delta<b$, i.e., $$\delta<x-a \ \ \text{     and   } \ \ \delta < b-x.$$ 
The claim is that such a $\delta$ exists. Do you see why?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable? is there a better reason

Comment: I don't see how uncountability could help here. Think about the fact that $\frac u 2 <u$ for every real number $u$.

Comment: For positive real $u$.the trick is to find a *positive* number separating $a,x,b$.